# Http client can't handle css and js

Tags: html, httpserver

I created an http server that can handle HTML, CSS, JS, jpg, ICO and GIF. I have a website to test my server and when I send the HTML page, the CSS and JS just print itself at the screen instead of activating
(The program itself works but only the CSS and JS appear at the screen).

An example to my server response:

```
http/1.1
200 OK
Content-Length: 26466
Content-Type: text/html; text/css; text/javascript; charset=utf-8
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gvahim Test Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/favicon.ico"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/doremon.css">
    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .st-container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            font-family: 'Josefin Slab', 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
```

(The response is much longer so I sent part of it).

Does my header causes it to happen? Is There another way to send an HTML, CSS, JS file?

Comment: Your content-type is wrong. Just because you have JS or CSS embedded in the html file, there's no need to put them all in the content-type header. The correct type is `text/html`. But if the browser puts the JS and CSS in the visible content, there is also something wrong with your html document.